# How can I respond in a definitive fashion to an app pestering me about a permission?

Tags: macos, accessibility

Why?

In that case, I think of Steam, which keeps requesting access to the Accessibility Panel. I don't think I want that, because Steam is not an Accessibility tool.

What?

I'd like to say "No, I don't want to give you access, stop asking".

NOTE: Buscar's answer clearly explains why it needs to be accessed, which makes the problem a non-problem.

Comment: Other than blocking it (silently) there is no such thing as fashion reply to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable & Control Access for Assistive Devices & Apps in OS X Mavericks](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/05/enable-access-assistive-devices-apps-mac-os-x/)

> For example, many popular games will require access to the Assistive
>   Devices abilities so that an online game can properly use voice chat
>   or screen broadcasting. This is true with nearly all Steam games,
>   ranging from Team Fortress 2 to Civilization V, and Blizzard / Battle
>   Net games like StarCraft 2 and World of Warcraft. Note these games
>   will continue to function without Assistive Access, but their feature
>   set for online communication and sharing may be limited, and thus if
>   you’re playing games and find the voice chat features aren’t working,
>   this setting or app-specific access could very well be the reason why.

You can not send a replay to it, but you can disable it in your sys pref security and privacy, and/or in the game set up.