# Steam keeps asking for accessibility features even though is has access?

Tags: macos, steam

This only happens to me on Yosemite. I gave Steam access as [per my previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147766/how-can-i-respond-in-a-definitive-fashion-to-an-app-pestering-me-about-a-permiss). Steam worked fine until the upgrade to Yosemite. What may have changed, and has anyone a clue how to fix that without deinstalling a few terabytes of video games?

Comment: Is Steam allowed in your Firewall ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 actually,  FireWall is off.

Comment: It should be not off for other reasons! Open it and add Steam to the allowed!

Comment: @Buscar웃 the machine is behind a dedicated firewall and IDS. This should not be a problem. I'm more curious of the reasons why you think the FW could be involved with the Accessibility Features request?

Comment: I am sure you know how to do that on Mavericks in Security-privacy (enable Steam accessibility), so why is it not working on 10.10? is the Steam showing in that window ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes it is showing. I'm actually considering doing a full reinstall fo the OS just for that small annoyance rather than find out the reason for myself, but I'd rather know before if I'm the only one with the issue... would be a shame to go through the hoops if some software update is on the way ^^

Comment: Steam is doing this for me as well. I assume Steam just needs an update for Yosemite.

Comment: Yosemite has nothing to do with this. I have not upgraded to Yosemite, in fact i didnt know about it until i was looking solution for the same problem you guys are having. I am still using Maverics and i have the same problem as you. It must be Steam bug or some Games we use on steam, i dont know, but i can confirm it cant be Yosemite. Thanks

Comment: @saba It might be two different cases though, because the issue appeared for multiple people at the time of the release of Yosemite. To be honest, as long as it is fixed, I don't care what was the root cause :) Thanks for chiming in though!

Answer (score 12):

A temporary fix (requires terminal):

1. `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/Tcc.db 'delete from access where client like "%Steam%"'`
2. Restart Steam
3. Allow steam access in accessibility via UI or something like: `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO access values ('kTCCServiceAccessibility','com.valvesoftware.steam',0,1,0,NULL);"`

Comment: Thank you for this, a very interesting insight on how the privacy database actually works under the hood. There apparently also is a tool called tccutil, but I did not look into it.

Comment: why is this a temporary fix?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but a lot of configuration changes made by some apps (specifically tanium which is used to monitor company issued computers) will cause these settings to change frequently and they do that by directly modifying this database... and they don't always do it correctly. Chances are that you have something on your laptop that is editing this in one way or another and it's a matter of time until you need to run the commands again. A better fix is to go through the API and get all the right parameters set... I don't know how to do that though and this quick and dirty hack works.

Comment: Y'all need to upvote this hack though :P, gotta reap that karma.

Comment: +1 - This seems to be a general solution to accessibility features access problems. Worked for Logitech software as well.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a known bug for Yosemite.

Steam has to be updated to work 100% with compatibility for Yosemite. Just wait for them to fix it.